# Angular: pick item from ng-repeat search results

Tags: angularjs

is it possible to pick/choose one result from ng-repeat search results and it will automatically go to input area?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="event.url_code" ng-change="searchAccountUrl();">
                        <div ng-repeat="result in accounts | filter: event.url_code" style="border: 1px solid #dee3e8">
                            <a style="cursor: pointer">{{result.url_code}}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

like angucomplete? or select tag, that you choose one option and it goes to input area as selected. and then ng-model = your choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want only one (or several) of the `<div>` within the `ng-repeat` to show up, if they match the value in the `input`?

You just need to use `ng-if` with your `ng-repeat`.  The `ng-if` will have knowledge of your current item within your `ng-repeat` iteration and if it shares a scope with the input, it'll also have knowledge of the model you use for `ng-model`.  No need for change handlers, etc.  Data binding will do all of it for you.

```
<input ng-model="myModel.url_code">
<div ng-repeat="result in accounts" ng-if="result.url_code == myModel.url_code">
    <strong>{{result.url_code}}</strong>
</div>
```

You can use a method like `.contains()` or whatever in place of `==` if you want to worry about partial matches.  Just add the method to your scope and it'll work.

**Edit:**
Based on your comments, you want something like:

```
<input ng-model="myModel.url_code">
<a href="" ng-click="setInputValue(result)" ng-repeat="result in accounts">{{result.url_code}}</a>

$scope.setInputValue = function(result) {
    $scope.myModel.url_code = result.url_code;
};
```

Comment: oooyaya thank you for replay, but i ment to pick one result from the list in ng repeat and select it. like angucomplete, or select tag

Comment: here my list [link](http://imgur.com/bMRHjyO), i want to pick one and it will go to input area as selected

Answer (score 1):

Use a ng-click directive which passes the string you'd like to insert into the input.

JS:

```
$scope.input = null;

$scope.replaceInput = function(e) {
    $scope.input = angular.element(e.srcElement).html());
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="input">
<div ng-repeat="foo in foos">
    <div ng-click="replaceInput($event)">{{foo.baa}}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The "it doesn't work part" is what you'll want to do - you don't need to pass the interpolated value.  You can pass the object reference or the url_code property of that object without interpolating it.

Comment: I've altered my answer now. Uses $event instead, which doesn't use interpolating at all.

Comment: Try using $event instead though. A bit more angular'y I'd say. :)

Comment: You already know the value you want so passing `$event` and getting that value from `$event.srcElement.html()` means you're looking it up even though you already know it.  For instance, you could just pass `foo` or `foo.bar` directly to the method.  For testing this is better as well, since you won't have to pass an event with `srcElemen` mocked out to return a jqLite instance which implements `.html()` in order to test the method..